# Send message from unknown type

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to have my iOS project send a message and have it handled by the common project.

However, the `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` needs to the know the sending type in order to subscribe.

Given this constraint, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just use `Object` as the type.  Everything in C# inherits from `Object`